# Writing the wav header for multiple channels

Tags: c#, audio, kinect, wav

Following the [wave file standard](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) to record audio data with Kinect, I wrote a `WriteWavHeader()` method which works perfect for 1 channel (PCM, Sample rate: 16 kHz, Bits/sample: 16). The problem is that when I try to record in stereo (`nChannels = 2`) it seems like the speed of the track doubles! Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
static void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int dataLength)
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(64))
    {
        int cbFormat = 16; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
        WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX()
        {
            //Subchunk1Size ==  16 for PCM.
            wFormatTag = 1,

            //NumChannels  :    Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
            nChannels = 2,

            //SampleRate       8000, 44100
            nSamplesPerSec = 16000,

            //ByteRate         == SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
            nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000*2,

            //BlockAlign       == NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
            nBlockAlign = 2*2,

            //BitsPerSample    8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
            wBitsPerSample = 16
        };

        using (var binarywriter = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
        {
            //RIFF header
            WriteString(memStream, "RIFF");
            binarywriter.Write(dataLength+8 + cbFormat+8 + 4); 
            WriteString(memStream, "WAVE");
            WriteString(memStream, "fmt ");
            binarywriter.Write(cbFormat);

            //WAVEFORMATEX
            binarywriter.Write(format.wFormatTag);
            binarywriter.Write(format.nChannels);
            binarywriter.Write(format.nSamplesPerSec);
            binarywriter.Write(format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
            binarywriter.Write(format.nBlockAlign);
            binarywriter.Write(format.wBitsPerSample);

            //data header
            WriteString(memStream, "data");

            binarywriter.Write(dataLength);
            memStream.WriteTo(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

And the recording method:

```
public void RecordAudio()
{
    //Subchunk2Size    == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
    int recordingLength = 5 *16000* 2 *2;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    using (FileStream _fileStream = new FileStream("c:\\kinectAudio.wav", FileMode.Create))
    {
        WriteWavHeader(_fileStream, recordingLength);
        int count, totalCount = 0;
        //Start capturing audio                               
        using (Stream audioStream = this.sensor.AudioSource.Start())
        {

            while ((count = audioStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 && totalCount < recordingLength)
            {
                _fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                totalCount += count;
            }
        }
         //write the real wav header
        long prePosition = _fileStream.Position;
        _fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        WriteWavHeader(_fileStream, totalCount);
        _fileStream.Seek(prePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        _fileStream.Flush();         
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you specifying stereo when you use your AudioSource? From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855698.aspx I couldn't see any way to actually change the captured format.

Comment: couldn't find it either. Actually I started a topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683610/recording-with-specific-kinect-microphones on how one could specify the desired microphones to use, but didn't get any feedback... Specifying nChannels=2 on the header however, when I opened the wav file in Audacity I got a result that looks like this: http://kozco.com/tech/audacity/Audacity1_playback.jpg (where the 2 channels are slightly different if you look close), which means that the output IS stereo, so I guess I'm doing something wrong with ByteRate/dataLength, but can't figure it out..

Comment: Just because you see two channels in Audacity doesn't mean that the source you've recorded from in your program is stereo - it just means you've told it it's stereo by saving that in the header. I'm guessing slightly but it's possible that audacity will be interpreting sample 1 as left channel sample 1, sample 2 as right channel sample 1, sample 3 as left channel sample 2, sample 4 as right channel sample 2, and so on - the result will be that you get very slightly different output in each channel and it will play double speed.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. The thing is that, as I've checked, it is possible to record with Kinect in stereo using Audacity (I'm pretty sure Audacity will be able to record 4 different tracks, with the appropriate sound card) , but this.sensor.AudioSource.Start() seems to record only in mono... Any wild guesses?

Comment: Sorry, I my only source is the docs and I didn't find them very helpful!